# Can I exclude a single SELECT in MSSQL from my WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query that pulls a lot of the information I need filtered by multiple WHERE clauses. However, I don't want the my main table (inv_data in this case) to be affected by all the WHERE clauses. Is there any way to choose which tables get affected by which WHERE?

Here's my current query:

```
$query_ats = "SELECT
                i.prod_cd as product,
                i.descrip as description,
                i.in_stock as current_stock, 
                SUM(p.log_qty) as purchase_order,
                SUM(l.order_qty + e.order_qty) as total_so
            from
                inv_data as i
                inner join plog as p
                    on i.prod_cd = p.prod_cd
                inner join ord_log as l
                    on i.prod_cd = l.prod_cd
                inner join ediordlg as e
                    on i.prod_cd = e.prod_cd
            where
                i.class_cd = 'ALG7'
            AND 
            dateadd(day, p.EST_DT, '18001228') BETWEEN getdate() and dateadd(day, 14, getdate())
            AND 
            dateadd(day, l.SHIP_DT, '18001228') BETWEEN getdate() and dateadd(day, 14, getdate())
            AND 
            dateadd(day, e.SHIP_DT, '18001228') BETWEEN getdate() and dateadd(day, 14, getdate())
            group by
                i.prod_cd,
                i.descrip,
                i.in_stock,
            order by
                i.prod_cd ASC";
```

Table i (inv_data) is my main table that I do not want affected by any of the dateadd clauses.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, through Left Joins with appropriate join criteria. To get help with your specific query you'd need to provide more details.

Comment: What information do you need? I tried Gordon Linoff's solution down there but it's giving me some repeat rows with different results inside

Comment: Can you provide the outputs your talking about and what information doesn't look right to you?

Comment: Previously the query only returned records where the "i.prod_cd" existed in all three tables. Now it only needs to exist in one to be included in the resultset, but this sounds like what you're asking for.

Comment: I think you may be right, because I'm getting multiple rows of the same items, but it's random (ie if I had multiple records of l.order_qty, it is returning a result for each one). I'm guessing I need to add something to the where clause?

Comment: The multiple rows of the same seems strange since you're only aggregating on records from [inv_data]. Can you give an example of the multiple rows?

Comment: actually you're right I'm not getting multiple row returns anymore... don't really know what happen earlier. Everything's actually working great, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left outer join the conditions and move the conditions to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT i.prod_cd as product,
       i.descrip as description,
       i.in_stock as current_stock, 
       SUM(p.log_qty) as purchase_order,
       SUM(l.order_qty + e.order_qty) as total_so
from inv_data i left outer join
     plog p
     on i.prod_cd = p.prod_cd and
        dateadd(day, p.EST_DT, '18001228') BETWEEN getdate() and dateadd(day, 14, getdate())
     left outer join
     ord_log l
     on i.prod_cd = l.prod_cd and
        dateadd(day, l.SHIP_DT, '18001228') BETWEEN getdate() and dateadd(day, 14, getdate()) 
     left outer join
     ediordlg e
     on i.prod_cd = e.prod_cd and
        dateadd(day, e.SHIP_DT, '18001228') BETWEEN getdate() and dateadd(day, 14, getdate())
where i.class_cd = 'ALG7'
group by i.prod_cd, i.descrip, i.in_stock,
order by i.prod_cd ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked as far as the filtering but I think the LEFT OUTER JOINS are screwing up the SUM data. Trying to see what the problem is right now.

Comment: @AndrewChen . . . Perhaps you are getting a cartesian product for each product, because the query uses different join dimensions.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, am looking up how I can go about fixing this, thanks for the input!

Comment: @AndrewChen . . . To fix the problem, use subqueries to aggregate the date for each table, by product code.  Then join together the aggregated results.

Comment: so something like SELECT (SELECT prod_cd as product, descrip as description, in_stock as current_stock from inv_data as Current_inventory), (SELECT ....)

and then join those new tables via left out join?

Comment: oh never just saw to aggregate the date. okay will try, thanks!